# Is there a way to use Elastic Beanstalk resources for a multi-region application deployment using CloudFormation StackSets?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

So I've been working on trying to deploy my application using both Elastic Beanstalk and CloudFormation. I've been doing some research on how I can get my application to deploy multi-region (Oregon and Virginia) by using CloudFormation StackSets.

The problem is that only the Oregon region creates successfully, but not the Virginia region. The error that comes back is that the Application Version Source Bundle can only reference one bucket and key from one region at a time. I've tried adding parameters, but it still comes back with an error.

Has anyone had a similar issue when working with Elastic Beanstalk multi-regionally? I'm also thinking that Elastic Beanstalk might not support multi-region in this way no matter how much configuration I do.

I've tried adding parameters and referencing them in my Application Version resource, adding two buckets with a replication rule and referencing the original bucket as the Source Bundle.

I've also tried adding a S3 Multi Access Point resource in my template and referencing it inside the Application Version Source Bundle, but it doesn't accept it as a valid reference.

I would appreciate any tips! Thanks!